# Overlay that transparent for touches in Android

Tags: android, overlay, android-touch-event

I want to put transparent overlay on part of the screen(draw over other apps). Can I make this piece "transparent" for touches and swipes(when user taps or swipes on this part it detects like normal tap or swipe for other apps)?

Comment: You can use [`WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE) to make your overlay "click through" and unaware of any inputs.

Comment: But when I swipe on the overlay that gestures aren't "visible" to other apps.

Comment: You cannot have an overlay that decides what gestures it wants to consume or let through. You either declare it as touchable or not.